# Performance issues using AppFabric caching

Tags: .net, caching, appfabric

I am finding that when AppFabric cache comes under heavy load it is resulting in unpredictable application behaviour.

Has anyone experienced anything similar?
Any thoughts on ideal configuration for AppFabric?

Comment: can you describe your configuration and what is this unpredictable behaviour?

Comment: AppFabric performance degrades drastically with high throughput on Single caching server, 128MB RAM restriction, 8 cores, SQL server, optimistic caching. AppFabric caching services is being utilized by an ASP.NET application.

Comment: how much data are you caching? why only 128 MB limit to the appFabric service?

Comment: Items in the cache do not get evicted when cache is full. Items in the  cache sometimes are evicted immediately.

Comment: No specific reason for only 128MB. The assumption is that items would be evicted as needed. Hundreds of MB being pushed through the cache.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the limits you have applied to AppFabric are the ultimate cause of your performance problem. That said, you may also want to ensure that you have configured the channelOpenTimeout and requestTimeout to some suitable values - the defaults are quite high and in many it cases it would be preferable to re-read the data from your data store rather than wait for AppFabric to respond.

```
  <dataCacheClient channelOpenTimeout="5" requestTimeout="1000">
    <!-- cache host(s) -->
    <hosts>
      <host name="localhost" cachePort="22233" />
    </hosts>
  </dataCacheClient>
```

Comment: What would happen if I have the limit of 128 and attempt to cache and item of 150MB?

Answer (score 0):

The maximum size of an object that can be cached by is 8 mb (by default). You can change it through advanced configuration properties if your production application is going to cache objects of that size. 
Regarding the other question: What happens if we try to pump 150 Mb data into cache of 128 Mb size. 
1. The objects will get evitcted using a best effort LRU and newer objects will replace them. 
2. If the incoming rate is faster than the rate of eviction, the cache might be throttled , blocking all writes for some duration.